# Trying to run an app that was built on VS Code through Android Studio. I keep getting an error that says an emulator is not found

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

```css
warn Invalid application's package name "project" in 'AndroidManifest.xml'. Read guidelines for setting the package name here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
**error** Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
```

The error keeps showing up even when I have my Android emulator up and running on my mac.

Comment: No emulator ...

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali I do have an emulator installed, it's just not being detected for some reason. It's something to do with gradlew I think